# background mode support/control for iOS EdgeEngine

Tags: edgeengine

I have the following use case that I would like to understand if the edgeEngine can support

1. iOS app is connected to a BLE device
2. iOS app sets up edge engine and deploys a microservice
3. iOS app is backgrounded (At this point the edgeEngine is paused)
4. iOS app gets BLE message from device while in background

During #4, is it possible to wake up the edgeEngine to make calls via microservice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue: Unable to make edge microservice API calls when the application is in the background.

Cause: edgeEngine Runtime is not running.

Remedy: It is the application’s responsibility to bring the application to the foreground when it needs to make API calls to the edge microservices. Therefor you can always call the mimik Client Library's startEdgeEngine before making the edge microservice calls.

Note: The mimik mimik Client Library helps with the process by automatically restarting the edgeEngine Runtime once the application comes back to the foreground.